# Returning value from actor call

Tags: c++, actor, c++-actor-framework

In C++ Actor framework I have an actor (lets suppose A) which calls another actor ( lets suppose B) and then the value of B has to be used in A's logic.

To make it more concrete the code is the following:

```
behavior B(event_based_actor* self) {
return {
    [=](const string& what) -> string {
        return what;
    }
};

behavior A(event_based_actor* self) {
return {
    [=](const string& what, const actor& buddy) -> string {
            self->request(buddy, std::chrono::seconds(10), what)
        .then(
            [=](string & data) {
                aout(self) << data << endl;
            }
          what = data // here I have to use data and thats the issue
           );
        return what;
    }
};
```

As can be seen in the code I have to use the data variable which is the result of the actor B outside the lambda and since I'm new to this any help would be appreciated.

And the actor B is called from another blocking actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work. Event-based actors are nonblocking. The statement `request(x).then(f)` sends `x` to another actor and then stores `f` for handling the result. In other words, `request(...).then(...)` always returns immediately and `f` is executed at some later point in time. Setting `what = data` thus achieves nothing and you will always return the original `what`.

What you are looking for are response promises. They allow you to delay the response. In your case:

```
behavior A(event_based_actor* self) {
  return {
    [=](const string& what, const actor& buddy) -> result<string> {
      auto rp = self->make_response_promise();
      self->request(buddy, std::chrono::seconds(10), what)
      .then(
        [=](string& data) mutable {
          aout(self) << data << endl;
          rp.deliver(std::move(data));
        }
      );
      return rp;
    }
  };
}
```

You can read more about promises in the [manual](http://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/MessagePassing.html?highlight=promise#response-promises) and there's also a full [example](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/examples/message_passing/promises.cpp) included in CAF.

Comment: But instead of just returning rp, I have do use it for calculations. So would using a blocking actor be the best solution. Or is there any other way?

Comment: You cannot do calculation with the promise. Returning this from the handler is only a placeholder, so that CAF knows that you produce a result later (I've updated the answer slightly: you cannot return just a `string`, it needs to be a `result<string>`).